# Problem with convergence of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

I've been having some problems trying to understand this:

$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$

I'm required to show that the integral is convergent using the comparison test:
If
$|f(x)|\le g(x)$ for all $x\ge a$ and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ and $\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$ exist for every $b\gt a$
then, if $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ is convergent so is $\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$.
But how am I supposed to choose  $g(x)$ ?
This is my wrong work:
First I noticed that the integrand is not continuous on $\left[ 0,\infty \right)$, but I deal with that later. Next I break the integral in two parts:

$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\int_{0}^{0.1}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx+\int_{0.1}^{\infty }\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ (I thought the smaller the interval the better.)

I start working on the first integral to test its convergence:
By the comparison test, I chose $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, because if $f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, then $g(x)\ge f(x)$ on $\left[ 0,0.1 \right]$.
Integrating:

$\int_{0}^{0.1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$, since the integrand is not defined at x=0 I write
$\int_{0}^{0.1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ = $\lim_{p \to 0+} \int_{p}^{0.1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ = $\lim_{p \to 0+} (\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}-2\sqrt{p})$ = $\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}$, so I know the first integral is convergent.

Now with $\int_{0.1}^{\infty }\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ I did almost exactly the same: I choose again $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ because $f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\le g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $\left[ 0.1,\infty \right)$.
But this time I obtain

$\int_{0.1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\lim_{b \to \infty }\int_{0.1}^{b}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\lim_{b \to \infty }(2\sqrt{b}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}})=\infty   $, which is divergent.
So I got a convergent integral and a divergent integral, something's clearly wrong.
I checked the book and in it the integral is broken as

$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty }\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$.

Why $\left[ 0,1 \right]$? Shouldn't any real number on $\left( 0,\infty  \right)$ be as valid? What's a good procedure to choose $g(x)$? Thank you.

Comment: For $0.1$ to $\infty$ you cannt do the same argument  as the one for  first interval. Use the fact that $\frac 1 {\sqrt x} $ is bounded.

Comment: It serves no purpose to split the integral into two parts if you are using the same argument for both parts.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}$.

From comparison test for improper integrals:

If $g(x)\geq f(x)\geq 0$ on $[a,\infty)$ then,

- if $\int_a^\infty g(x)$ converges then so does $\int_a^\infty f(x)$
- if $\int_a^\infty f(x)$ diverges then so does $\int_a^\infty g(x)$

In your second case on the interval $[0.1,\infty)$, you have found that $g(x)$ diverges which doesn't imply $f(x)$ diverges.

Now, to find information about $f(x)$ on the whole interval, the motivation of the book is probably:

Let's separate $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$ such that the divided integrals converge.
Say the book divided it to 2 integrals.

$\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$=$\int_0^a f(x) dx$+$\int_a^\infty f(x) dx$

Like how you did , now we analyze
$\int_0^a g_1(x) dx$+$\int_a^\infty g_2(x) dx$ instead.

We know that,  $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ converges and thus we have got our first $g(x)$ which satisfies the comparison test condition.

Now, $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ diverges so we can't rely on this to be our second $g(x)$. So we search for a new $g(x)$ which satisfies the comparison test.

Let's choose $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$

We know that $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx$ converges and thus we have got our second $g(x)$ which satisfies the comparison test condition.

Comment: Why 1/x^2? Is there any calculation/procedure to get g(x)? Also can I choose ANY g(x) as long as g(x)≥f(x)≥0 on [a,∞)? I mean, for example, g(x)=x^2 is bigger than f(x) on [1,∞).

Comment: You can use any other function instead of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ too. In general, one we can use $\frac{1}{x^p}$ such that $p>1$. But there are other functions that can be used. I choose that because $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^p}$ and $\int_1^\infty  \frac{1}{x^p}$ convergence is pretty well known and that's the first function type that came to me.

Comment: To answer your second question.

Yes, we can use any $g(x)$ but your question requires you to prove convergence and if you use $g(x)=x^2$ for your second $g(x)$, it won't help at all as this function is not convergent on $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: I see it now thanks to your last reply. Since $\int_{1}^{\infty }x^2dx$ goes to infinity and therefore is divergent. So I must choose g(x) in such a way that g(x)≥f(x)≥0 on [a,∞) but also being defined when limits are taken, am I right?

Comment: Like a rational function or a square root.

Comment: Yes, $g(x)$ can be any function as long as the the inequality is followed and is convergent.

Comment: Also, sorry because I should have asked this earlier, but why did I fail choosing $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ if the conditions for the comparison test were met?

Comment: For that particular $g(x)$, it was divergent so it didn't tell any information about $f(x)$ on $[a,\infty)$.

But we want $g(x)$ such that follows the inequality and is also convergent as if $g(x)$ is convergent then $f(x)$ at $[a,\infty)$ would also be convergent.

Comment: What you said earlier: $\int_{a}^{\infty }\frac{1}{x^{p}}dx$ is convergent if $p\gt 1$ and for the case of $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ it was divergent since $p=\frac{1}{2}\lt 1$. Correct?

Comment: Yeah, but instead of $\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{x^p}$ it should be $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^p}$.

Comment: Right. You helped a lot. I really appreciate your patience, thanks.